# why does my dictionary get me "None" as value?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic = {'A':'D','N':'Q','B':'E','O':'R','C':'F','P':'S','D':'G','Q':'T','E':'H','R':'U','F':'I','S':'V','G':'J','T':'W',
         'H':'K','U':'X','I':'L','V':'Y','J':'M','W':'Z','K':'N','X':'A','L':'O','Y':'B','M':'P','Z':'C'}

user_input = input("Enter the word: ").upper()
Key=str(user_input)
print (dic.get(Key))
```

This is my dictionary but the only answer I get is `None`

I tried to change the end to this but problem stayed :(

```
user_input = input("Enter the word: ").upper()
print (dic.get(user_input))
```

does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I *think* this is Python and tagged it that way, but please [edit] the tags if I'm mistaken @Milana

Comment: Just tried your code. It works for me.

Comment: yeah you are right sorry. im pretty new here so im learning!!

Comment: hm maybe its a jupyter problem than, i tried it to work in different files but the result is the same. is says "none" in the end without even any errors

Comment: You don't need to call `str()` on `user_input` as it's already a string.

Comment: What do you enter as a word? If you enter `A` this will give you `D`. If you enter `ABC` this will give you `None` as there is no `ABC` as key.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how a dictionary is working.

If I guess correctly, you would like to get `DEFG` when you enter `ABCD`.
What you currently do works only for **single letters** (if you run `dic.get('A')` you will have `'D'`, but `dic.get('ABC')` will output `None` as `'ABC'` is not a key).

I believe what you want is to perform some kind of substitution cipher, which is easily done with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
dic = {'A':'D','N':'Q','B':'E','O':'R','C':'F','P':'S','D':'G',
       'Q':'T','E':'H','R':'U','F':'I','S':'V','G':'J','T':'W',
       'H':'K','U':'X','I':'L','V':'Y','J':'M','W':'Z','K':'N',
       'X':'A','L':'O','Y':'B','M':'P','Z':'C'}

# define a translation table
table = str.maketrans(dic)

# get user input and translate
user_input =input("Enter the word: ").upper()
print(user_input.translate(table))
```

Example:

```
Enter the word: ABCD
DEFG
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the values in the string:

```
dict_a={'A':'D','N':'Q','B':'E','O':'R','C':'F','P':'S','D':'G','Q':'T','E':'H','R':'U','F':'I','S':'V','G':'J','T':'W',
         'H':'K','U':'X','I':'L','V':'Y','J':'M','W':'Z','K':'N','X':'A','L':'O','Y':'B','M':'P','Z':'C'}
user_input =(input("Enter the word: ")).upper()
key=user_input
print(''.join([dict_a.get(k) for k in key]))
```

And do not call a `dict` `dict` give it a name that does not conflict with the default classes.

Comment: thanks im going to try it out!!